# VACUUM is significantly slower in Postgresql 13 compared to Postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, vacuum

After switching to Postgresql 13 (13.6) from Postgresql 12 (12.10), we noticed that the manual VACUUM operation takes significantly more time, often more than double compared to Postgresql 12. Which is really strange given that Postgresql 13 supports parallel vacuum.

We run vacuum like this in version 13:

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE, PARALLEL 2) my_table
```

and in version 12:

```
VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE my_table
```

This is run after massive data insertion (billions of rows), on four tables. We did not perform version upgrade, instead we created a new RDS instance for Postgresql 13. The tables are used only for reading after inserting the complete dataset.

The times needed for the VACUUM statement have gone (34m -> 81m) for the smallest table and (370m -> 815m) for the largest one.

Unfortunately we don't have the output of the VACUUM command available. Is there anything that could lead to such a huge time increase between these two versions?

**EDIT 2022-12-14:**
Here's the output of VACUUM command from version 12:

```
 INFO:__main__:INFO:  vacuuming "public.table_1"

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  index "table_1_pkey" now contains 1545723861 row versions in 4191167 pages
 DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
 0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
 CPU: user: 7.43 s, system: 14.21 s, elapsed: 150.62 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  index "table_1_col_b_idx" now contains 1545723861 row versions in 8128097 pages
 DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
 0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
 CPU: user: 12.50 s, system: 28.37 s, elapsed: 154.44 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  index "table_1_col_a_idx" now contains 1545723861 row versions in 6904914 pages
 DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
 0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
 CPU: user: 11.60 s, system: 31.21 s, elapsed: 141.95 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  "table_1": found 0 removable, 1545723861 nonremovable row versions in 14866347 out of 14866347 pages
 DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 830
 There were 0 unused item identifiers.
 Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
 0 pages are entirely empty.
 CPU: user: 195.56 s, system: 402.60 s, elapsed: 2043.27 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_16415"

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  index "pg_toast_16415_index" now contains 0 row versions in 1 pages
 DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
 0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
 CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  "pg_toast_16415": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out of 0 pages
 DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 830
 There were 0 unused item identifiers.
 Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
 0 pages are entirely empty.
 CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  analyzing "public.table_1"

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  "table_1": scanned 300000 of 14866347 pages, containing 31191198 live rows and 0 dead rows; 300000 rows in sample, 1545663909 estimated total rows
```

and from version 13:

```
INFO:__main__:INFO:  vacuuming "public.table_1"

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  launched 2 parallel vacuum workers for index cleanup (planned: 2)

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  index "table_1_col_b_idx" now contains 1557689525 row versions in 8216885 pages
 DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
 0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
 CPU: user: 12.89 s, system: 26.59 s, elapsed: 118.25 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  "table_1": found 0 removable, 1557689525 nonremovable row versions in 14980412 out of 14980412 pages
 DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 864
 There were 0 unused item identifiers.
 Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
 0 pages are entirely empty.
 CPU: user: 3375.73 s, system: 258.42 s, elapsed: 4788.42 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_16416"

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  "pg_toast_16416": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out of 0 pages
 DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 864
 There were 0 unused item identifiers.
 Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
 0 pages are entirely empty.
 CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  analyzing "public.table_1"

 INFO:__main__:INFO:  "table_1": scanned 300000 of 14980412 pages, containing 31194184 live rows and 0 dead rows; 300000 rows in sample, 1557672428 estimated total rows
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything in there to explain the difference in duration. Only a confirmation of the longer time required in PostgreSQL 13. Some notes:

- Output for some index vacuuming is missing in version 13. I'm not sure why that is; could be because indexes are being handled by parallel workers? Also could be that some output may be missing since psycopg2 keeps only the last 50 messages in `conn.notices` attribute.
- The number of rows is slightly larger in v13 run; this is due to our normal weekly dataset growth and it should not be enough to explain the difference in time. In fact, prior to the v12 run there had been another v13 run with less data that still took more time.

I've been skimming though the different / newly introduced configuraton options (actually RDS parameter groups) between PostgreSQL 12 and 13... could `maintenance_io_concurrency` setting be a factor? It was introduced in version 13 and has a default value of 10. I am wondering that because we are performing multiple maintenance operations concurrently, via different client sessions (one session per table; 4 tables in total). What would be the equivalent `maintenance_io_concurrency` value in PostgreSQL 12?

Comment: Are you using the same hardware in both cases?

Comment: If it is reproducible, you can get the output of the VERBOSE next time (or maybe you can find it some log file).  If it is *not* reproducible, I don't think you will ever get a credible answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, we are using the same "hardware" (RDS instance type).

Comment: @jjanes yes, it is reproducible. We will try to capture the output of the VACUUM command, thanks.